# How to include space in the current regex answer to do the following?

Tags: regex, gedit

I would like to convert this:

```
ATOM   6990  CB  ILE A 1028     -0.558  90.754  9.341  0.00  0.00    +0.015 C
ATOM   6991  CB  ILE A 1028     -0.558  90.754  19.341  0.00  0.00    +0.015 C
```

Into this:

```
ATOM   6990  CB  ILE A 1028     -0.558  90.754   9.341   0.00  0.00    +0.015 C
ATOM   6991  CB  ILE A 1028     -0.558  90.754  19.341   0.00  0.00    +0.015 C
```

I tried using lookahead but my simple alteration to the current answer did not work for me. As i have a lot of similar anomalies i have to use regex.

Comment: Please name your regex flavor/tool.

Comment: Please give examples which should match and a few similar ones which however should NOT match.

Comment: ok. i did it. thanks.

Comment: Which regex engine does gedit use?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here.  The input and output look almost identical.

Comment: sorry i just edited it again. It is the first line at 9.341 which misses one space.

Comment: Regex alone isn't the right tool for this job.  You need to go back to whatever generated this tab-delimited file and re-export with fixed column widths.

Comment: Thats my biggest fear because it is not possible :(. I can try using a regex generator with the dataset if this is too complex.

Comment: You removed all information on your attempts, your thinking, your code. This is unwise, since it gives the impression of being a "give the code" question. Please edit the question so that it provides all information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of digits be fixed, e.g. at 5, you could use a fixed width positive lookbehind followed by some sort of capture group, e.g.

```
(?<=[0-9]{5})(\s+)
```

Comment: and how do i use it in reverse? lets say i have (tab)10002? (\t+)(?<=[0-9]{5}) would not work.

Comment: Use a positive _lookahead_, maybe `(\s+)(?=[0-9]{5})`

Comment: Please edit your question and tell me what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Okay. Done! :)) had to edit twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
\d+(\s+)
```

Decimal digits followed by whitespace in a capturing group.